# The input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, mysql

I get a "input string was not in a correct format" error when using the value from a textBox through a boxing to insert in a mysql database.

```
using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Datacon.con))
{
    MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(Datacon.query, conn);
    f2 f21 = new f2();
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Projet", f21.textBox1.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N-facture", int.Parse(f21.textBox2.Text));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total-HT", float.Parse(f21.textBox3.Text));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Retenue-garantie-10%", float.Parse(f21.textBox4.Text));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Retenue-avance", float.Parse(f21.textBox5.Text));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Montant-HT", float.Parse(f21.textBox6.Text));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TVA", float.Parse(f21.textBox7.Text));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TTC", float.Parse(f21.textBox8.Text));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payement1", float.Parse(f21.textBox9 . Text));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date1", Convert.ToDateTime(f21.textBox10.Text));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payement2", float.Parse(f21.textBox11.Text));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date2", Convert.ToDateTime(f21.textBox12.Text));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payement3", float.Parse(f21.textBox13.Text));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date3", Convert.ToDateTime(f21.textBox14.Text));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payement4", float.Parse(f21.textBox15.Text));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date4", Convert.ToDateTime(f21.textBox16.Text));
    conn.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

and this is the line where the exception is thrown:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N-facture", int.Parse(f21.textBox2.Text));
```

I have tried to solve this with `TryParse` and replacing `.Text` with the `Tostring()` method but neither seem to work

Comment: The value of textbox is a `non integer` or `empty`.

Comment: You need to check all the fields that need a conversion with the appropriate TryParse.....

Comment: Possible that input string has empty space. try to trim the value as `int.Parse(f21.textBox2.Text.Trim())`

Comment: thanks for the suggestions i will try

Comment: You could try Convert.ToInt32(), but if parse doesn't work than convert will probably not work too.  Trimming sounds like a good idea.  Otherwise make sure f21.textBox2 is the right textBox